# Rails route scope default based on current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a route something like:

```
scope ":department", department: /admin|english|math/, defaults: { department: 'admin' }
```

Is it possible to make the default department for this route to be based on the `current_user.department.name`?

If this is not possible, what is another way of solving my problem. The problem is that I want all links to default to the current scope unless otherwise noted. I'm currently doing the following in LOTS of places:

```
# links to /math/students
link_to 'students', students_path(department: current_user.department.name.downcase)
```

Comment: No. `current_user`, which is a method of your controller, doesn't exist until routing has been performed and a controller/action have been selected and a controller has been instantiated.

Comment: If this isn't possible, then how can I overcome my problem. I've updated my question w/ more details.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly, what you want is to be able to write:

`link_to 'students', students_path`

and have the department option automatically set based on the current user.

Here's a solution that's like some of the others that have been offered: define helpers for each route that requires a department. However, we can do this programmatically.

Here we go:
`app/helpers/url_helper.rb`

```
module UrlHelper

  Rails.application.routes.routes.named_routes.values.
    select{ |route| route.parts.include?(:department) }.each do |route|
      define_method :"department_#{route.name}_path" do |*args|
        opts = args.extract_options!
        if args.size > 0
          keys = route.parts - [:department]
          opts.merge!(Hash[*keys.zip(args).flatten])
        end
        opts.reverse_merge!(department: current_user.department.name.downcase)
        Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.send(:"#{route.name}_path", opts)
      end
  end

end
```

You now have helper methods like `department_students_path` for *every* route that has a `:department` path segment. These will work just like `students_path` -- you can pass in opts, you can even set the `:department` explicitly and it will override the default. And they stay up to date with changes to your `routes.rb` without you having to maintain it.

You might even be able to name them the same as the original helpers, i.e.,

`define_method :"#{route.name}_path"`

without having to prefix them with `department_`--I didn't do that because I'd rather avoid naming collisions like that. I'm not sure how that would work (which method would win the method lookup when calling it from a view template), but you might look into it.

You can of course repeat this block for the `_url` helper methods, so you'll have those in addition to the `_path` ones.

To make the helpers available on controllers as well as views, just `include UrlHelper` in your `ApplicationController`.

So I think this satisfies your criteria:

1. You can call a helper method for paths scoped to `:department` which will default to the `current_user`'s department, so that you don't have to explicitly specify this every time.
2. The helpers are generated via metaprogramming based on the actually defined named routes that have a `:department` segment, so you don't have to maintain them.
3. Like the built-in rails url_helpers, these guys can take positional args for other path segments, like, `department_student_path(@student)`. However, one limitation is that if you want to override the department, you need to do so in the final opts hash (`department_student_path(@student, department: 'math')`). Then again, in that case you could always just do `student_path('math', @student)`, so I don't think it's much of a limitation.

Comment: This would work but wouldn't this add the `department` argument to routes that don't even accept this attribute? So for example if I link to `about_path` (which is at the root level and not in a department) I would get `/about?department=math`

Comment: Yes, that's correct. That's what I meant about you might want to define this only on a subset of controllers or add some other logic. If the only links you care about adding this to automatically are routes for the `StudentsController`, for example, you could define this on that controller rather than `ApplicationController`

Comment: The link to the about page is on __every__ page in my application in the footer. This makes it impossible to implement your solution without the side effect that I mentioned above.

Comment: Alright, I see the problem - default_url_options actually doesn't work quite how I expected it to. Will edit answer above with a modified solution, although it will involve monkey-patching rails.

Comment: I was wrong, we don't actually need to monkey patch. See above.

Comment: I'm definitely liking this solution but there seems to be a problem w/ it. If I call `department_students_path` in the controller it's undefined. If I call it in the view however everything works as expected. Is there a way to load this into the controller level?

Comment: The helper is just a module, you can `include UrlHelper` in `ApplicationController`

Comment: Almost there. It seems like this doesn't work when doing something like `department_student_path(@student)`. I get `undefined method `reverse_merge!' for #<Student:0x007faff150ee18>`

Answer (score 1):

Route contraints can accept a proc, so you could solve this problem with the following "hack":

```
concern :student_routes do
  # all your routes where you want this functionality
end

# repeat this for all departments
scope ":department", constraints: lambda{|req| req.session[:user_id] && User.find(req.session[:user_id]).department.name.downcase == "english"}, defaults: { department: 'english' } do
  concerns :student_routes
end
```

Route concerns is a feature of rails 4. If you don't use rails 4, can you get the feature with this gem: https://github.com/rails/routing_concerns.

You can also just copy all the routes for students to all of the scopes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
link_to 'students', polymorphic_path([current_user.department.name.downcase, :students])
```

This will call

```
math_students_path
```

So to work I suppose you should add in your routes

```
scope ':department', as: 'department' do
  ...
```

`as` key generates helpers of the form: `department_something_path`

As that line is too long you could extract that to a helper

```
# students path taking into account department
def students_path!(other_params = {}, user = current_user)
  polymorphic_path([user.department.name.downcase, :students], other_params)
```

Then you will use in your views

```
link_to 'students', students_path!
```

Comment: I'm not accessing `/students?department=any_department`. I've updated my question to indicate the URL. Also, I don't like the idea of having to make a helper for each of my routes. This will get very ugly, very quickly

Comment: I don't understand how this will get ugly.

Comment: Well because I have hundreds of routes. I just provided the students resource as an example. I don't want to have to implement a helper for each of these. Also, if my route name changes for some reason I will have to update the helper as well to keep the naming in sync.

Answer (score 0):

What about using nested routes? You could implement this with:

```
resources :departments do
  resources :students
end
```

If you want to use a friendly url (like "math" instead of an id) can you add the following to the department model:

```
  # in models/department.rb
  def to_param
    name.downcase
  end
```

Remember name have to be unique for each department. Ryan B have made a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url-revised) about this. You could also use a gem like [friendly id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id).

You can now add the following to your views:

```
# links to /math/students
link_to 'students', department_students_path(current_user.department)
```

If you use this often, then create a helper:

```
# helpers/student_helpers.rb
def students_path_for_current_user
  department_students_path(current_user.department)
end

# in view
link_to 'students', students_path_for_current_user
```

Comment: I want to _not_ pass the current users's department all over the place. Also, I would need to make a helper for *every* route that I have

Comment: Sorry, but at least it's a much shorter way to write it (without helpers). There is no "good" way to do what you want, but i have posted a hack that maybe could help.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up specifying it in the `ApplicationController` with:

```
def default_url_options(options={})
    {department: current_user.department.name}
end
```

The path helpers will fill have the `:department` parameter filled in automatically then...